# array Index Out Of Bounds Exception in merge sort in java

Tags: java, mergesort

I wrote this code for merge sort in java, where i try to use merge sort using only one auxillary array. But it results in array out of bounds exception. Please help me fix the code for mergeSort with 1 auxillary array.

```
public static void mergeSort(int arr[], int s, int e){
        if(s < e){
            int mid = s + (e-s)/2;

            mergeSort(arr, s, mid);
            mergeSort(arr, mid+1, e);

            merge(arr, s, mid, e);
        }
    }

    public static void merge(int arr[], int s, int mid, int e){
        int arr2[] = new int[arr.length];
        for(int i = 0;i <= e; i++){
            arr2[i] = arr[i];
        }

        int i = 0, j = mid+1, k = s;

        while(i < mid+1 && j < e+1){
            if(arr2[i] < arr2[j])   arr[k++] = arr2[i++];
            else    arr[k++] = arr2[j++];
        }

        while(i < mid+1)    arr[k++] = arr2[i++];
        while(j < e+1)  arr[k++] = arr2[j++];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a subtle mistake in your code. In the merge method, you're using a different index to iterate over arr2 and arr. This is the main cause of your ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

To fix the code, note the following points:

When copying from arr to arr2, you should only copy elements from s to e, not the whole array.
The indices i and j should start from s and mid + 1 respectively for arr2.

Here's the corrected version of your merge method:

```
public static void merge(int arr[], int s, int mid, int e){
    int arr2[] = new int[arr.length];
    for(int i = s; i <= e; i++){
        arr2[i] = arr[i];
    }

    int i = s, j = mid + 1, k = s;

    while(i <= mid && j <= e){
        if(arr2[i] < arr2[j]) arr[k++] = arr2[i++];
        else arr[k++] = arr2[j++];
    }

    while(i <= mid) arr[k++] = arr2[i++];
    while(j <= e) arr[k++] = arr2[j++];
}
```